# Pass a value from a parent pathless route to a child route

Tags: remix.run

I'm aware that nested routes run in parallel but is there any way to pass a value from a parent pathless route to a child route and access it in the loader?

The parent pathless route performs the authentication. I just need to access the ID of the logged in user in the child routes.

My V2 directory structure looks like this:

```
_app.jsx           // Auth is performed here
_app._index.jsx
_app.page1.jsx
_app.page2.jsx
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of Remix v2.6, you cannot pass data from a parent loader to a child loader.

However, there are RFCs for both Middleware (which authentication is probably the primary use case) as well as Server Context. There is no ETA on when those will be available, though.

I recommend storing the user id in a cookie (or session). Then, you can access the data in every request.

Middleware RFC https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/7642

Server Context RFC https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/7644

Comment: The app runs in an iframe and cookies are blocked.

I can access the user data on the client via a JWT but that doesn't resolve the issue of accessing the data in the loader before the client loads.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a new approach here like this -
you may keep user id or any other auth related information to a Context API that you can place on root file.

**References:**

- [remix.run > root](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/file-conventions/root)
- [Passing Data Deeply with Context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context)